# My LapTop Internal Hard Drive is Not detecting

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, data-recovery

I am using HCL Leap top model Laptop. It is 5 years old one. The internal 160gb hard drive is not detected. I enquired nearby data recovery agents for data recovery and they informed me that head part of the hard drive was damaged and it need to be replanted with new one or to be repaired. I cannot do this on my own i guess. The Data Recovery agent demands me 480USD and it is not negotiable. Please help me for any other solution. I dont know the exact cost of head part of the lap top internal hard drive..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are most likely facing is you are running into "specialist" territory. Depending on what is wrong, $480 is not unreasonable for this type of recovery.  That said (and speculating - of-course I have not seen your hard drive or report), it sounds like the controller circuit on your drive is faulty.   It may very well be possible to replace this yourself - I have done this in the past.  The difficult bit will be finding an *identical*  (ie identical, not similar) model drive and swapping the board.  Try looking on E-Bay, and realise there is substantial risk involved in this procedure - if your data is worth more then $480 then get an expert to do it.

If the "head" of the drive is really the part that is stuffed, that is not something you can fix yourself - you would need very specific skills, and, importantly a "clean room" - as well as another drive.    That said, I would expect the drive to be detected and make funny sounds if it were a problem with the head.

Another thing - if the agent was really talking about "repairing" the drive, as opposed to "repairing the drive for long enough to pull the data off",  find another agent.   Once a drive has failed, you can't trust the drive long term (it might work, but the risk far outweighs the cost of a new drive - and drives are dirt cheap relatively).  Part of the problem is that the controller stores information specific to the drive (like bad/remapped sectors and other information typically layed down during the [destructive to data] process of creating the drive - think of something like a format, but at a much lower level)

Comment: Thanks David. I am thinking about consulting with my lap top manufacturer brand, HCL about this. I have already tried all low level process like format and other. As you said, it need to be done by a specialist in clean room.

Comment: Huh ?  If you have attempted a low level format, what did you do with the data.  If the data is not important, simply throw the drive away.  (You will also find that HCL don't make hard drives, they are most likely buying Western Digital, Seagate or Hitachi drives, so they may not be much help, except possibly for warranty replacement of the actual drive itself)

Comment: Oh! I did not do anything with the data. hard drive is not detected. So i stopped there and now i am looking for solution to get my data inside it. And i found a company named Stellar who quoted me 480USD for recovery by repairing or replacing head in their lab which is clean like you said. But i can't afford 480 USD for my 5 years family photos there.. But it is important to me.

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss.  The only things I can suggest are getting a second quote (but I don't expect it will be much cheaper), or putting the drive in a safe place and waiting until you can afford to attempt to recover it - although the longer you wait the harder it will become to do.  (I'm still skeptical that it requires a cleanroom.  Do you have a report and/or description of drive sounds you can post up ?  Also, what make and model drive do you have?)